# How to prevent UITextViewDelegate added as object to Storyboard Scene from being deallocated? ARC

Tags: ios5, interface-builder, automatic-ref-counting, uitableview

I have a fairly straightforward app with a couple UITextFields that should only have positive numbers in them (some integers, some decimal).  I created two UITextViewDelegates to perform validation on the text fields when textFieldShouldEndEditing and textFieldShouldReturn are called.

I added two Object items to my Storyboard Scene and assigned one class to each and connected the delegate of each textfield to the proper delegate object.

Unfortunately the delegates are being deallocated when [textField canBecomeFirstResponder] is called. I have a semi-hackish fix in place where I use a IBOutletCollection to keep a reference to each delegate. Ideally I shouldn't have to do that.

Is this something that can be tweaked in IB/XCode or is this just an ARC related problem that I can't fix myself?